# Function that is defined for all reals and is continuous but not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

To grasp the concept of Uniform Continuity, I was looking at [examples from previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381389/continuous-but-not-uniformly-continuous-example) of functions that are continuous on a defined region *A*, but not uniformly continuous.

But that begs the question about whether or not there exists a function that is defined for all x ∈ R, that is continuous, yet is not uniformly continuous? I couldn't find any such examples, does such a function exist?

Comment: You can use $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.
I wonder why every example I look at keeps on using $1/x$ defined on (0,1), I think $x^2$ is a much better example.

Comment: There's some good commentary on the wiki page for uniform continuity 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity: 

"Continuous functions can fail to be uniformly continuous if they are unbounded on a bounded domain, such as $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$ on (0,1), or if their slopes become unbounded on an infinite domain, such as $$f(x) = x^2$$ on the real line. However, any Lipschitz map between metric spaces is uniformly continuous, in particular any isometry (distance-preserving map).

Comment: [Possibly of interest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249552/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$()= x^2$

Thanks to [Elchanan Solomon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/647/elchanan-solomon).