# proof verification: $f(x) = 1/x$ is not uniformly continuous on the open interval (0,1).

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I've written a proof that $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on the interval $(0,1)$ and would like to know if it is correct. Here's what I've got.

> In order to show a function $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $A$, it
>   suffices to show there exist two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $A$
>   and an $\epsilon_0>0$ satisfying $\lim(|x_n-y_n|)=0$ but
>   $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\ge\epsilon_0$.
>
> Let $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $y_n=\frac{2}{n}$, with $n\ge3$, and set
>   $\epsilon_0=\frac{3}{2}$. Then $\lim(|x_n-y_n|)=0$, but
>
> $\left|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{y_n}\right|=\left|n-\frac{n}{2}\right|=\frac{n}{2}\ge\epsilon_0=\frac{3}{2}$,
>   as desired.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Refer here if you want to see an older discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371905/proving-fx-1-x-on-0-1-is-not-uniformly-continuous

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate. The two questions concern the same theorem, but ask for specifics about different proofs of it.

Answer (score 1):

Proof is absolutely correct.

If you take $x_n$$=$$1/n$. And $y_n$$=$$1/(n+1)$ then you don't have to put extra thing I.e. $n\leq3$